# Returning and using a pointer to a multidimensional array of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I'm trying to access the 'room' array via functions in the room class itself, i.e:

```
 class ship{

    room * rooms[3][4];
 public:

   room ** getrooms(){

       return *rooms;
   }

 }


class room{

  //variables...
  ship * ship_ptr;
  public:
     getShipPtr(); //assume it returns the pointer to the class ship
     void function_x(){
    this->getShipPtr()->getrooms()->rooms[x][y]->doThat();
      }
  }
```

I'm doing something wrong pointer-wise but I'm not really sure, what could correct the code so I can access the room array out of the ship class?
Note: Assume that the rooms are already initiated

Comment: What part of the code is supposed to check to make sure the access to `rooms` is not out of bounds?

Comment: I didn't put it here, for simplicity's sake, and because that's not a problem (at least for now) @crashmstr

Comment: It is tagged C++, hence get used to std::array and std::vector and do not allocate a single value for a member variable (avoid new/delete)

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm not allowed to use either std::vector or std::array, my professors insist that I take 'this way'

Comment: Do you want a matrix of rooms or a pointer to an uninitialized and unallocated matrix of rooms?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I alredy had them initialized, (my bad, will edit to say that), I merely want a pointer to the rooms

Comment: @Zetsuno `rooms` is the array, `*rooms` is not the array.

Comment: Why do the rooms need to know about the ship?  Looks like either a flaw in the design or a circular reference:  ship->room->ship->room...  It's like having a vector of integers and each integer refers to the vector.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When I need to move units (which are inside a vector in the class room), I need to make it go through the ship, because the ship is the one that knows how many rooms exist, and which coordinates are valid/invalid. It might be a fail, as you say, but I'm too neck deep in the code and if I change it's base now, I might as well start anew.

Comment: Are you telling the room to move the units or *the ship to move a unit from room A to room B*?  Subtle, but important here.  You'll have more problems if you tell the room to move to the units.

Comment: @Zetsuno so you are saying that you should not be accessing the rooms array from the ship, but get a room from the ship's rooms to act upon?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tell the ship to move a unit from room A to room B through a function in the class room which sends the current pointer of the room to a function in ship, and the coordinates of the new location, then updates the person.

Comment: @crashmstr I access a function in the class room, which send a pointer of the current room and the new coordinates to a function in ship, which updates the person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm doing something wrong pointer-wise but I'm not really sure

You are making the false assumption that a 2D array can decay to a pointer to a pointer just like a 1D array can decay to a pointer.

```
int arr1[10];
int* ptr1 = arr1; // OK. 1D array decays to a pointer.

int arr2[10][20];
int** ptr2 = arr2; // Not OK. 2D array does not decay to a pointer to pointer.

int (*ptr2)[20] = arr2; // OK. ptr2 is a pointer to "an array of 20" objects.
```

My suggestion:

Simplify your code and change the interface to:

```
room* getRoom(size_t i, size_t j){
   // Add checks to make sure that i and j are within bounds.
   return rooms[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. And you were right, I was assuming that 2D arrays would decay into a pointer like 1D arrays do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to insist on using `std::vector`s etc, although your teacher should teach you to use them from the very beginning. So let's stick to writing C in C++. You cannot return a 2D array as a double pointer, as the former **does not decay** to the latter. If you insist in returning a pointer to your array, what you need is

```
room* (*getrooms())[4] // define a function returning a pointer to array-4 of room*
{
    return rooms;
}
```

That is because a 2D array of type e.g. `T arr[A][B]` decays to a pointer to array-B of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the root cause of your issue is the cyclic dependency of having `rooms` know about the `ship` and the `ship` know about the `rooms`.

I suggest a different design:

```
class Ship
{
  Room ship_rooms[3][4];  // Note, not dynamically allocated.
  public:
    void move_unit(Room& from_room, Room& destination)
    {
      destination.set_unit(from_room.get_unit());
    }
    void move_unit(unsigned int from_row, unsigned int from_column,
                   unsigned int dest_row, unsigned int dest_column)
    {
      ship_rooms[dest_row][dest_column].set_unit(ship_rooms[from_row][from_column].get_unit());
    }
    Room& get_room(unsigned int row, unsigned int column)
    { return ship_rooms[row][column]; }
};
```

In the above design, the `Ship` is in charge of moving units between rooms.  Rooms will get (cut) units or set units (receive them).  This eliminates the need for a room to know anything about the Ship.

Another possible design is for a room to move something to another room:

```
class Room
{
  Item unit;
  public:
    void receive_unit(const Room& other)
    {
      unit = other.unit;
    }
    void transfer_unit(Room& other)
    {
      other.unit = unit;
    }
};
```

The above structure allow rooms to communicate with each other, **without knowing anything about the ship or container**.

Note:  These designs resolve the issue of pointer by not requiring pointers.  References are used instead.

*Downvoters:  Please add explanation in the comment.*